# SSIS package hangs on validation

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created my first SSIS package. I have a for each container the loops thru a folder. The data flow has a derived column task and 4 lookups. When I run the package in Visual Studio (2013) it starts with the first file and arrives at the destination, but it does insert the data it only hangs with the text "Validating OLE DB Destination 1" in the status bar.

The files are located on my hard drive and the destination database is on the locale network. I'm using a sysadmin account the be sure that the user have sufficient access rights.

I'm unable to query the destination database table from SSMS as well.

Anyone have some idea what could be the problem and how I could solve it?

Sorry for the unspecific question. In my control flow in ssis I have a for each loop container who contains a data flow task to import all the data in every file that the container loops. Connected to the task, is two move file tasks dependent on success or failure of the import task. The strange part is that one file i moved, no data is inserted in the database and the for each loop hangs after the first loop (the folder contains 150 files). While this ssis process hangs, i'm unable to to query the database with select *, no error it just says "executing query".

The latter. It finishes the first round (moves the file to my success folder) and then halts with the "still working" icon on the data import task. But the data is not inserted even if the file is move. Will the transaction commit first when it has finished processing all the files?

Edit: Image of the control flow and the data flow
[image: Control flow and data flow]

Comment: Cant' read or write to the table? You need to solve your connectivity/security issue. Can you connect to the SQL Server? Can you read other tables?

Comment: I'm using the a sysadmin user. So reading and writing should not be a problem.

Comment: In your post you said you were unable to query the destination database so clearly it is!

Comment: That is correct, the query hangs is I beleive there has to be some sort of lock on the table by the process. But I have all the correct access rights.

Comment: Are you saying that using SSMS, you can log in to the server OK and you can run a select without an error message but no data comes back in a timely fashion? You really need to be more specific and provide more details for us to have a clue. Is it a simple select on a table, or is it a view, or is it a query with joins?

Comment: Sorry for the unspecific question. In my control flow in ssis I have a for each loop container who contains a data flow task to import all the data in every file that the container loops. Connected to the task, is two move file tasks dependent on success or failure of the import task. The strange part is that one file i moved, no data is inserted in the database and the for each loop hangs after the first loop (the folder contains 150 files). While this ssis process hangs, i'm unable to to query the database with select *, no error it just says "executing query".

Comment: In the package is your data flow task yellow (still running) or does it get through the first data flow and start the second and then get stuck on yellow? To be honest this may be difficult to troubleshoot

Comment: The latter. It finishes the first round (moves the file to my success folder) and then halts with the "still working" icon on the data import task. But the data is not inserted even if the file is move. Will the transaction commit first when it has finished processing all the files?

Comment: Its difficult to work it out. What happens if you just right click on the data flow and execute it manually for one file? Does it finish OK? Does it still lock the table?

Comment: Disable the Failure route's move file task. Does everything suddenly work? If you can, pop a screenshot of your package and the data flow and click the Edit button and add them in. Have you fiddled with the Transaction settings within SSIS?

Comment: After some testing removing different components I removed the destination database connections and suddenly the loop continued. So the question is why does it halt when trying to insert the data into the database.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was found in the "lock table" option. Since both destinations are the same table, i guest the first destination locks it, when the second destination hits the same table it is locked and it waits until it is unlocked. And that does not happen since its not ready to commit yet.